# SSSD installation directory is empty

Tags: linux, centos, sssd

When I try to install SSSD using `yum install sssd` terminal writes that installation completed fine, but when I try to `service sssd start` it writes

> sssd: unrecognized service

Then when I attemp to start it using `/etc/init.d/sssd start` I get an error

> Starting sssd:                                             [FAILED]

Also I can see that `/etc/sssd` directory is empty (service fails to start **because it miss sssd.conf file**, which must be located in this empty directory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sssd` ships unconfigured. You must [create at least one domain](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/Configuring_Domains.html) before starting the service. See the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/SSSD-Introduction.html) for full information on using sssd.

Comment: A basic config template should be included... even if it's something like, "copy sssd.conf.default to `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`"

Comment: @ewwhite For which identity provider? There are so many to choose from.